Unable to scroll website even when changing body overflow to scroll
Im learning html and decided to make a mock version of a website. When I try to scroll with my mouse it wont work. It doesn't show the scroll bar either.
I have read that I should change my body ovreflow to scroll,and it did in fact add a scroll bar, but now I can't add elements below what I have already put in there. So when I try to add a paragraph under my div, but it wont show. Don't mind the text,
The code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Relmercc</title>
   <link rel="icon" href="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=U5Pp4XpKz9ap&format=png&color=000000">
    <style>
        .header{                                               
            background-color: #404040;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            position: fixed;
            width: 1904px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .header-logo-img{                        
         
            height: 150px;
        }
       
        .right_header{                           
            color: #fff; position: absolute; top: 60px; right: 100px; font-size: x-large; font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        .yappin{         
            background-color: #8fe3c6;
           height: 744px;
           border: none;
           border-radius: 8px;
           font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        .spacing2{height:7px}  
        .spacing3{height:100px; background-color: #8fe3c6; border: none;border-radius:8px;} 
        .yapintxt{               
            margin-right: 100px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            color: white;
            font-size:x-large; 
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
        body {
 height: 1360px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: scroll;
}
    
    
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "header">
            <img class="header-logo-img" src="C:\Users\Stepan\Downloads\Relmercc-23-07-2024.png" alt="My Image"> <div id="spacing1">
                <span class="right_header">Buy clothes</span>
            </div>
    <div class ="spacing2"></div>   
    <div class = "yappin">
            <div class = "spacing3"></div>
            <p  class = "yapintxt">Relmercc has reached the very top among the dynamic scenes that change with every beat in style, through the amalgamation of modern taste with environmental sustainability. With innovation through ethical production as the very premise upon which this brand was based, Relmercc has made a niche for itself within the cutthroat competition in modern clothing. The brand is proud of its craftsmanship, shown in every single stitch—from traditional techniques with the incorporation of state-of-the-art design. With Relmercc, every piece basically strikes a balance between style and conscience, which appeals to the conscientious consumers who seek trend-setting looks and sustainable choices.</p>

            <p  class = "yapintxt">Basically, sustainability is at the heart of Relmercc's philosophy. Most fast fashion giants are not so close to environmental accountability, but Relmercc does its best to be friendly to the environment across the supply chain. From responsible sourcing and production to more thoughtful designing in order to reduce wastes, all decisions are made considering the welfare of the planet. Through such championing of transparency and accountability, Relmercc has set new standards in the industry and inspired a generation of mindful consumers to make informed choices about their fashion purchases. For the brand, this is an incredibly clear imperative: A rising community of people finds sustainability at the heart of modern living.</p>
            
            <p  class = "yapintxt">Moreover, Relmercc stands to lead the way in the charge for inclusivity and diversity in fashion. This brand celebrates the beauty of individuality, embracing differences in its designs and catering to an extraordinarily wide spectrum of tastes and preferences. Embracing inclusivity places Relmercc at the heart of building a platform that makes fashion a way for every being to express themselves. From gender-neutral collections to size-inclusive ranges, Relmercc empowers people to confidently be themselves in clothes that fit well but embody personal values. Basically, Relmercc represents more than a clothing brand but a step forward toward an all-inclusive, more mindful high-fashion future.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class = "spacing2"></div>
    



You have got everything wrapped in a div with class header, and header is fixed. Incidentally, you haven't given complete code (e.g. body not closed). You may find putting your code through a validator will help make sure you have matching opening divs for example see e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

i may or may not have the right answer but can you try fixxing your scrolling issue by adjust the body and HTML to have height: 100% and overflow: auto. Set your .header to position: fixed; width: 100% and add margin-top: 170px to .yappin to position it below the header. This should allow you proper scrolling and display of elements.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for your response. I did everything just like you told (except the 170px margin-top part, because it just creates a big gap between the divs) and it did in fact add a scroll bar but it just won't work. It is there, i can press on it, it reacts, but when I add elements that are below my view and try to scroll - it just doesnt. I will put my code in the next message

so apparently my code is too ling and I can't add it here, but I also might add that the grey rectangle inside the scroll bar takes all the space up, instead of being like a small one instead.

Do not assign width or height of any main elements which should be full width or height in pixel and instead using "header" as a class use <header>.


body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color: #404040;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
.header-logo-img {
    height: 150px;
}
.main-section {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.right_header {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.yappin {
    background-color: #8fe3c6;
    height: 744px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.spacing2 {
    height: 7px;
}
.spacing3 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #8fe3c6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.yapintxt {
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-size: x-large;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <img class="header-logo-img" src="C:\Users\Stepan\Downloads\Relmercc-23-07-2024.png" alt="My Image">
                <div id="spacing1">
                    <span class="right_header">Buy clothes</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-section">
                <div class="spacing2"></div>
                <div class="yappin">
                    <div class="spacing3"></div>
                    <p class="yapintxt">Relmercc has reached the very top among the dynamic scenes that change with every beat in style, through the amalgamation of modern taste with environmental sustainability. With innovation through ethical production as the very premise upon which this brand was based, Relmercc has made a niche for itself within the cutthroat competition in modern clothing. The brand is proud of its craftsmanship, shown in every single stitch—from traditional techniques with the incorporation of state-of-the-art design. With Relmercc, every piece basically strikes a balance between style and conscience, which appeals to the conscientious consumers who seek trend-setting looks and sustainable choices.</p>
                    <p class="yapintxt">Basically, sustainability is at the heart of Relmercc's philosophy. Most fast fashion giants are not so close to environmental accountability, but Relmercc does its best to be friendly to the environment across the supply chain. From responsible sourcing and production to more thoughtful designing in order to reduce wastes, all decisions are made considering the welfare of the planet. Through such championing of transparency and accountability, Relmercc has set new standards in the industry and inspired a generation of mindful consumers to make informed choices about their fashion purchases. For the brand, this is an incredibly clear imperative: A rising community of people finds sustainability at the heart of modern living.</p>
                    <p class="yapintxt">Moreover, Relmercc stands to lead the way in the charge for inclusivity and diversity in fashion. This brand celebrates the beauty of individuality, embracing differences in its designs and catering to an extraordinarily wide spectrum of tastes and preferences. Embracing inclusivity places Relmercc at the heart of building a platform that makes fashion a way for every being to express themselves. From gender-neutral collections to size-inclusive ranges, Relmercc empowers people to confidently be themselves in clothes that fit well but embody personal values. Basically, Relmercc represents more than a clothing brand but a step forward toward an all-inclusive, more mindful high-fashion future.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="spacing2"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>



